# How to update a aprimary key field with linq to SQL?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have tbl_names with following fields:

```
Id  int
Name nvarchar(10)
family nvarchar(20)


Id    Name    Family
 1     John     Smith
```

and suppose `Id` and `name` are primary key together(compound primary key).
and I want to update `name` field according to the value of `Id` field.

```
DataclassesContext dac=new DataClassesContext();
var query=from record in Dac.tbl_name where record.id=1 select record;
query.name="Raymond";
Dac.Submitchanges();
```

but I encounter following error:

```
Value of member 'co_Workshop' of an object of type 'Tbl_Workshop' changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.
```

Is it because of `name` field is primary key? why can't I update a primary key field using linq?

Comment: I can't think of a time I've updated a primary key, ever.  Not saying you don't have a reason to... I just never have.  Interesting that it won't let you.  It might be because it is the only identifier it can link to the database?  So you'd have to make a copy of it with the updated key, add it, and delete the old one.

Comment: Why would you have a conjoined identity of `{id, name}`? Why not just keep `id` unique?

Comment: I'm working on an old database an can't change it's structure. yes you are right there is no reason but I need it

Comment: @Micjecito could you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that you should find a way around this. I cannot imagine why it would be a good idea to change a value in a PK. The entire nature of a PK is that it is a stable identifier of the row.

In your case, you should drop and recreate the PK to be just the "Id" field and then if you need to improve performance on queries filtering on "name" then just add an Index on the "name" field. The fact that you only use the "Id" field to find the record supports this idea.

EDIT:
I answered before there were comments to the Question. Now that I see the comment from the OP about "it is an old database and can't change it's structure", I would say that if there are no FKs pointing to this PK then this should be a fairly straight-forward change (to drop and recreate the PK with just the "Id" field as I mentioned above).  If there *are* FKs pointing to it then an option (though not a great option and it might not work on all RDBMS's) is to:

1. Drop the FKs
2. Drop the PK
3. Create the new PK on just the "Id" field
4. Create a UNIQUE INDEX on "Id" and "Name"
5. Recreate the FK's to point to the UNIQUE INDEX

This will work on Microsoft SQL Server and as much as I dislike the idea of a FK pointing to a UNIQUE INDEX, it should allow for the same structure that you have now *plus* LINQ will just see the single field PK on "Id" and allow for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Where possible, a workaround is to delete the record whose primary key value needs updating and create a new record in its place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are ways around it, like I mentioned above.  Linq won't let you change the primary key.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/64064c2d-1484-4a00-a2c4-764bcb6b774a

Comment: I tried it, but there is no Remove() method. `DAC.tbl_names.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For legacy reasons, I couldn't remove the column I needed to update from being part of the primary key.

A simple solution was to not use Linq in this case, but use T_SQL and do a simple update.

```
update tbl_name set name = 'Raymond' where id = 1
```