# LinqToSQL A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

am trying to update an `Item` which some of it's members changed so am doing it like this

```
public void Update(IItem pItem) {
    using(GameDBDataContext db = new GameDBDataContext()) {
        Item old = db.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == pItem.Id);
        if(old != null) {
            Item item = pItem as Item;

            old.id = item.id;
            old.type = item.type;
            old.owner_id = item.owner_id;
            old.player_id = item.player_id;
            old.currentdura = item.currentdura;
            old.maxdura = item.maxdura;
            old.location = item.location;
            old.socketprogress = item.socketprogress;
            old.firstsocket = item.firstsocket;
            old.secondsocket = item.secondsocket;
            old.effect = item.effect;
            old.composition = item.composition;
            old.bless = item.bless;
            old.isfree = item.isfree;
            old.enchant = item.enchant;
            old.suspicious = item.suspicious;
            old.islocked = item.islocked;
            old.color = item.color;
            old.compositionprogress = item.compositionprogress;
            old.inscribed = item.inscribed;
            old.inscribetime = item.inscribetime;
            old.amount = item.amount;

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

but every time I try to update the item it throw this exception!

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Value of member 'location' of an object of typ
e 'Item' changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one ins
tead.
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.CheckForInvalidChanges(TrackedObject trac
ked)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at Database.Managers.ItemManager.Update(IItem pItem) in d:\CProgramming\DarkS
iders.Core\Database\Managers\ItemManager.cs:line 59
```

not sure what is wrong here :-s!?

Comment: Take a look in the database, is the location mapped to a column that's part of your primary key perhaps?

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932299/how-to-update-a-aprimary-key-field-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to modify the id of record which could not be modified probably identity column. If you do not have to update the id of record then remove this statement

```
old.id = item.id;
```